# Microsoft Azure API List All Tenants

Tags: rest, microsoft-graph-api, multi-tenant, azure-api-management, azure-api-apps

We are a CSP partner with MS. My goal is to call the Azure API and list all the different tenants we have in our account.

I found this Azure API resource that appears to allow the listing of all tenants: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/Tenants/List

I’ve been able to implement the authorization code flow, and I can call MS Graph API’s successfully. However when I try to call this API I receive this response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "AuthenticationFailed",
        "message": "Authentication failed."
    }
}
```

I feel like it may an issue with the permissions I've granted in my app registration, but I can't seem to figure what is needed to make it happen.

I wish there was a way to use the MS Graph API to get all of our tenants, but from my research that doesn't exist.

Comment: Are you still looking for any help on this question?

Comment: Yes I was never able to get it working...

Comment: can you please provide error message detail with correlation id and time stamp and also please let us know are you looking for Ms graph?

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed the bear token. I test this api by postman.

You can read this article.

[**Get an Azure Active Directory token using Azure Active Directory Authentication Library**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/aad/app-aad-token)

[image]

Comment: I've got a bearer token. I'm using the same token to call https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/organization. Can you describe how you are getting your token a bit more? Are you using the auth code flow with client secret?